# Getting brightness from the camera

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to find a way of getting the brightness value from the camera while the camera is open, but preferably without capturing an image. I just want to know the level of light that's coming into the camera (before the phone adjusts anything). I understand that you can analyse an image and evaluate the luminosity, but that's not quite what I'm after.

Comment: thanks John - saw that post but that covers how to analyse an image, not the open camera